# GTK/GTK+ Cygwin program help

Tags: c, makefile, cygwin, gtk

I recently installed cygwin on my windows 7 machine which I installed all the packages that came with cygwin. Now i have a simple "Hello World" program in C code that uses GTK objects. When I type make and compile the program in CYGWIN, it gives me a big error:
"gtk/gtk.h: no such file or directory"
........... and it goes on an lists bunch of GTK errors

doesnt CYGWIN include GTK? If it does I am pretty sure I installed it. Is there another plugin for GTK and cygwin i dont know about? I really need this to work for my course throughout the semester. Aprreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned Cygwin does not include Gtk. You can download Gtk for windows on http://www.gtk.org/download-windows.html, I recommend you download the all-in-one bundle.

Comment: "it gives me a big error: "gtk/gtk.h: no such file or directory" That's because the linker is not finding gtk files.

Comment: ok i get that its not finding the files..any way i can make it work with cygwin?

Comment: so say that I download the all in one GTK package for windows. Where can I put it so that the compiler can access it as a normal C library?

Comment: The easiest way is to add it where gcc store the standard libraries.

Comment: any idea where that is located? sorry im a noob

Comment: This is plain wrong: you cannot mix different runtime libraries (GTK+ official runtime for windows has always been compiled with MinGW) and expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

GTK+2 is included in Cygwin [since 2004](https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2004-07/msg00003.html): you *must* install those packages, or the equivalent ones in Cygwin current.

Once done you can use `pkg-config` to feed the compiler with the proper flags. Being Cygwin really a POSIX distro, [the standard documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/gtk-compiling.html) will apply.

Furthermore, be careful regardling the order of the arguments because (sadly) the official documentation [is wrong](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2010-February/msg00035.html).